# Unity Javascript Making a Good Collider

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

So, I am working on a game in Unity and I have some issues with my colliding. The problem is that the car that I made will sometimes glitch next to the wall and wont move back or forward. even though it's not colliding. What I've done is I added 2 empty gameobjects. Named them front and back bumper and added a script that is activated when the bumpers hit a wall. If the front bumper hits a wall it can't go forward and if the back one hits a wall it can't go backwards. But this isn't really that good. I need to know how to setup a good collider because this really is annoying when you play. Also the car can go up to 50 speed.

Comment: Perhaps you should instead find out why it's glitching next to the wall.

Comment: Well my code is good but Unity is a bit unstable when it comes to JS. Mostly I find an alternative way of doing something with JS that fixes the problem but I can't fix this. It's been bothering me since I started making this game :/

Comment: Your code isn't "good" if it's unstable and UnityScript (Similar to JS but not the same language) isn't inherently broken. If you wrote equivalent code in C# it would still mess up. Unity's collision detection and handling is actually really good.

Comment: The code is alright, the collider is the problem. The car would stop somewhere next to a wall and no collider is touching this. And when I removed the main car collider, not the bumper colliders, it worked fine except the fact that the car would glitch through the wall, so I'm pretty sure that it's not code related.

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information about your problem, then. Some visual aids would help, particularly screenshots of your scene and the problem exhibited, if you feel it's the collider configuration and not your underlying code that is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the car can collide at high speeds into the wall, I would consider using a specific collision detection for the car's rigidbody.

There are some collision detection methods that are used to prevent fast moving objects from passing through other objects without detecting collisions.

From Unity's documentation :

- **Discrete :** Use Discrete collision detection against all other colliders in the scene. Other colliders will use Discrete collision detection when testing for collision against it. Used for normal collisions (**This is the default value**).
- **Continuous :** Use Discrete collision detection against dynamic colliders (with a rigidbody) and continuous collision detection against static MeshColliders (without a rigidbody). Rigidbodies set to Continuous Dynamic will use continuous collision detection when testing for collision against this rigidbody. Other rigidbodies will use Discreet Collision detection. **Used for objects which the Continuous Dynamic detection needs to collide with**. (This has a big impact on physics performance, leave it set to Discrete, if you don’t have issues with collisions of fast objects)
- **Continuous Dynamic :** Use continuous collision detection against objects set to Continuous and Continuous Dynamic Collision. It will also use continuous collision detection against static MeshColliders (without a rigidbody). For all other colliders it uses discreet collision detection. **Used for fast moving objects**.

As you can see, you should use **Continuous** detection for the walls and **Continuous Dynamic** detection for the car.

**Warning :** Don't forget that **Continuous** detection has a **big impact on performance**, you should only use it if you have collision issues and in the minimum possible amount of objects.

Comment: Maybe a good idea would be to change the detection type in the script depending on the speed ?

Comment: I would emphasize that bit about "big impact on performance."  Might be easier just to trigger a "bounce back" animation when the colliders touch.  Actual physics simulation is often very expensive.

Comment: ok, so I've figured out what's actually wrong. So when I hit a wall it just keeps going forward because I set it to go forward if you release the forward key and backward... you get the point, it's how it works in the real life. Now I need to just recode it a bit and it's done.

Comment: I just saw that you wrote the same thing I want to do xD anyways I'll check as accepted bcs I learnt something new and colliding is actually a lot better with this even with this bug

Comment: Sounds great ! Thanks.

Comment: performance would be a non-issue in the example at hand, regardless of settings